# Call a function on a react child functional component from parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a very large and complex React application. It is designed to behave like a desktop application. The interface is a document style interface with tabs, each tab can be one of many different type of editor component (there are currently 14 different editor screens). It is possible to have a very large number of tabs open at once (20-30 tabs). The application was originally written all with React class components, but with newer components (and where significant refactors have been required) I've moved to functional components using hooks. I prefer the concise syntax of functions and that seems to be the recommended direction to take in general, but I've encountered a pattern from the classes that I don't know how to replicate with functions.

Basically, each screen (tab) on the app is an editor of some sort (think Microsoft office, but where you can have a spreadsheet, text document, vector image, Visio diagram, etc all in tabs within the same application...  Because each screen is so distinct they manage their own internal state.  I don't think Redux or anything like that is a good solution here because the amount of individually owned bits of state are so complex.  Each screen needs to be able to save it's current working document to the database, and typically provides a save option. Following standard object oriented design the 'save' function is implemented as a method on the top level component for each editor. However I need to perform a 'save-all' function where I iterate through all of the open tabs and call the save method (using a reference) on each of the tabs. Something like:

```
openTabs.forEach((tabRef) => tabRef.current.save());
```

So, If I make this a functional component then I have my save method as a function assigned to a constant inside the function:

```
const save = () => {...}
```

But how can I call that from a parent? I think the save for each component should live within that component, not at a higher level. Aside from the fact that would make it very difficult to find and maintain, it also would break my modular loading which only loads the component when needed as the save would have to be at a level above the code-splitting.

The only solution to this problem that I can think of is to have a save prop on the component and a useEffect() to call the save when that save prop is changed - then I'd just need to write a dummy value of anything to that save prop to trigger a save... This seems like a very counter-intuitive and overly complex way to do it....  Or do I simply continue to stick with classes for these components?

Thankyou,
Troy

Answer (score 0):

> But how can I call that from a parent? I think the save for each component should live within that component, not at a higher level.

You should ask yourself if the component should be smart vs dumb (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/react-smart-dumb-components).

Consider the following:

```js
const Page1 = ({ onSave }) => (...);
const Page2 = ({ onSave }) => (...);
const App = () => {
  const handleSavePage1 = (...) => { ... };
  const handleSavePage2 = (...) => { ... };
  const handleSaveAll = (...) => {
    handleSavePage1();
    handleSavePage2();
  };
  return (
    <Page1 onSave={handleSavePage1} />
    <Page2 onSave={handleSavePage2} />
    <Button onClick={handleSaveAll}>Save all</button>
  );
};
```

You've then separated the layout from the functionality, and can compose the application as needed.

Comment: The problem I see with this approach is that the handleSavePage methods are outside of the code for the pages themselves.  There is something to be said for separation of concerns and loose coupling - but this actually tightly couples the parent page to the children.  At the moment, adding a new screen requires only adding the name of it's class to the main App function... With the above approach the handleSavePageX functions need to be at the top level so every time a new page is added you also have to add it there.. And that breaks my code-splitting modules as well.

Comment: You already have the tight coupling to your parent when you iterate through your ref array. `React.Lazy` would solve your code-splitting issue. Alternatively, `handleSaveAll` could fire an event that each page subscribes to, which then calls the individual save functions.

Comment: The handleSavePage functions would need access to all of the state inside the pages as well. If it is called from the page then they could pass what they need as parameters, but if called from the top-level, how do those methods get the state they need from the components? Moving the state into the top level would again make it very tightly coupled as the application is very modular with the intent to 'plug-in' new screens without changing the core (other than currently adding the component to the list of available components - which I would also like to get away from)

Comment: That is what state store solutions like redux are used for.

Comment: I am using React.Lazy for the code splitting... That's my point, the save logic is lazy loaded with the component when needed - if it were at the top level then that would not be the case anymore.
However: "handleSaveAll could fire an event that each page subscribes to, which then calls the individual save functions" -  Do you suggest  BroadcastChannel? I had not thought of that. I am currently using lots of Broadcast Channels for the screens to interact with each other where needed and for popout windows, so that could work for this purpose too I suppose.

Comment: "That's my point, the save logic is lazy loaded with the component when needed - if it were at the top level then that would not be the case anymore." I doubt the save logic is significant in size to worry about, you should measure it prior to worrying about it. You can also use lazy imports to if needed.

Comment: Yeah it's not really performance that's my main concern, it's maintainability. The complete built and deployed application is currently around 40mb, but since it's always delivered over local LAN I'm not really too concerned about size - but I still want to be as efficient as I can where there are opportunities... More important though is simply maintaining clear modularity of the codebase so that developers can focus on their own components and develop to contract without having to touch the rest of it.

Answer (score 0):

```
I don't think Redux or anything like that is a good solution here because the amount of individually owned bits of state are so complex.
```

I don't know if for some reason Redux is totally out of the picture or not, but I think it's one of the best options in a project like this.

Where you have a separated reducer for each module, managing the module's state, also each reducer having a "saveTabX" action, all of them available to be dispatched in the Root component.

Comment: Perhaps.. I don't really know redux or understand it's use-case. I come from a server-side development background and when I looked at Redux it seemed to complicate matters greatly. The codebase currently consists of 103 classes, most of which have state... But it is very modular so individual parts can be operated on in isolation without having to work with common datastores.   A user could have 6 or 7 "Workflow Editor" screens open at once, each workflow screen has it's own independent state that manages it's workflow document and the current UI control states..

Comment: Ideally I'd like customers to be able to add their own custom extensions to the application without having to modify anything in any of the existing files...  The back-end server side of it loads plugins dynamically from the filesystem so a customer just needs to write a plugin and compile it and drop it into the plugins directory and it is loaded. I'd like that same ability on the front-end as well ideally but I haven't figured out a way to implement it.

Comment: I don't want to get into details about the application itself, it is a financial business application used for trading. The application itself runs only in-house on a LAN and is never served over the internet, with a grid of servers running the back-end code and customers accessing the UI via either web or Electron. But to give an idea of the complexity of the UI application itself, it's something similar in scale to Unity or Unreal game engines, or maybe an application like Blender.